# How do I convert .dmg to .img?

Tags: file-conversion, g5

How do I convert DMG files to IMG files?  I am trying to use 'Q emulator' to run XPpro and it requires an IMG file of the XP disc.(legal copy)  I'm using a late model G5 PPC with Leopard 10.5.8

Answer (score 10):

According to a [very old source](http://forums.macresource.com/read.php?1,160169) [circa 2006]

> In Terminal,
>
> `hdiutil convert disk.dmg -format RdWr -o disk.img`
>
> where disk.dmg is the path to your image (input) 
>   and disk.img the output image

Comment: This works in 10.11 El Capitan.

Comment: Gives me `hdiutil: convert failed - image/device is too large` :'(

Comment: This command has worked for me on macOS Sierra, but the `.img` file is 4x larger than the dmg. Which I presume is normal?

Comment: this doesn't work on Sonoma

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
hdiutil convert <input.dmg> -format UDTO -o <output.img>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a brute force method.

If writing a script, then use the commands below.

```
NODE="$(hdiutil attach -nomount <input.dmg>)"
echo "$NODE"
NODE="${NODE%% *}"
dd if="${NODE/disk/rdisk}" bs=1m of=<output.img>
hdiutil detach "$NODE"
```

Otherwise, if entering by hand, then follow these steps.

1. Enter the command below to attach. From the ouput, note the `/dev` node assign to the image. Here I will assume this is `/dev/disk2`.

   ```
   hdiutil attach -nomount <input.dmg>
   ```
2. Write the contents.

   ```
   dd if=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m of=<output.img>
   ```
3. Eject.

   ```
   hdiutil detach disk2
   ```